# Django Error Logging

Tags: python, django

I am using Django + Python + Gunicorn + Nginx + MySQL stack to make a social dating website - http://www.tomonotomo.com

My settings.py file in Django is as follows:

```
DEBUG = False
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = False

ADMINS = (
    ('Pratik Poddar', 'xxxxxxxxxxx'),
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

FAILED_RUNS_CRONJOB_EMAIL_PREFIX = "[Django - Tomonotomo - Cron Job] "
EMAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX = "[Django - Tomonotomo] "

.....
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
)

LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
         }
     },
     'formatters': {
       'verbose': {
        'format': '%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(module)s %(process)d %(thread)d %(message)s'
        }
      },
      'handlers': {
           'null': {
          'level': 'INFO',
          'class': 'logging.NullHandler'
       },

           'mail_admins': {
              'level': 'ERROR',
              'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
           }
      },
     'loggers': {
           'django': {
          'handlers': ['null'],
          'level': 'INFO',
          'propagate': True,
        },
            'django.request': {
               'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
               'level': 'ERROR',
               'propagate': True,
            },
      }
 }
```

My gunicorn config (edit: supervisor config) is as follows:

```
 stdout_logfile = /home/ubuntu/gunicorn_tomonotomo_supervisor.log
 redirect_stderr = true
```

My nginx config has :

```
 access_log /home/ubuntu/tomonotomo-access.log;
 error_log /home/ubuntu/tomonotomo-error.log error;
```

I am not able to see my error log. I do not want to make debug = True as it is in production. I am not getting any mails as well.

I am looking to get have all the logs in a file and have all the errors emailed me every day in the morning. How can I implement that?

Thanks a ton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

stdout_logfile and redirect_stderr are not valid gunicorn config file options.

You need accesslog and errorlog as mentioned here:

http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/configure.html#accesslog